# Win 10 - Task scheduler not running when specifying a domain account as local admin

Tags: windows, windows-10, active-directory, group-policy, scheduled-tasks

I have a gpo that adds a domain account to be a member of the local administrator group on a domain joined pc. I can see the user is part of that group, and have the task scheduler set to run whether that user is logged in or not and at startup/log on of any user.

However, the task doesn't run at all (it doesn't even show up under task scheduler library)

The user is also a domain admin(doesn't work with this type of membership either).

If i change it back to system account, it works as expected whether i log in as domain user or local user.

Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the basic things first.

1. Check if the service is stopped from 'Services'.
2. If on, stop and restart the service, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd>

All the best!

Comment: The service is on..it starts working as soon as i switch accounts.